# How can I add Previous/Next Link to Wordpress Recent Posts Widget?

Tags: wordpress

Hey everyone,
I wanted to add a previous / next link below my recent posts widget. The default wordpress widget shows the most recent 5 posts, but I want the user to be able to scroll through all of my posts through this widget, so if they click previous it would show them the next five posts.

I have searched high and low, but couldn't find anything :/ (or for that matter any widget that does ths). Would appreciate the help from any code monkeys. No preference on how it is implemented, ajax, page refresh etc.

Comment: is the widget going to be in the sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to do pagination; all you need to do then is modify the default widget code.

http://wpcanyon.com/tipsandtricks/the-easy-way-to-make-wordpress-ajax-pagination-using-jquery/

This might also be just the plugin you need:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ajax-recent-posts/

Hope this helps!